# How to add a border on HTML5 Canvas' Text?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can draw text using the below code,

```
myCanvas.fillStyle = "Red";
myCanvas.font = "30pt Arial";
myCanvas.fillText("Some Text", 10, 30);
```

But I want to add a border around "Some Text", any ideas on that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `strokeText()` and the `strokeStyle.` eg:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("myc");
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.strokeStyle = 'black';

context.font = '20pt Verdana';
context.fillText('Some text', 50, 50);
context.strokeText('Some text', 50, 50);

context.fill();
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myc"></canvas>
```

Comment: wao! I have never seen such an "executable" answer in SO before. Is that a new feature?

Comment: work because the font is big but if the font is small this no work like it suppose

Comment: @Emiliano how would that work? If the text is so small then i would just fill text without a border because I don't think the end user even would notice the border

Answer (score 5):

We can use **strokeStyle** method to draw border around the text or outline, and We can use **lineWidth** method to define the width of the stroke line.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas01');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeStyle= "red"; //set the color of the stroke line 
ctx.lineWidth = 3;  //define the width of the stroke line
ctx.font = "italic bold 35pt Tahoma"; //set the font name and font size
ctx.strokeText("StackOverFlow",30,80); //draw the text
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas01" width="400" height="400" style="border:2px solid #bbb; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -4):

What about

```
myCanvas.style.border = "red 1px solid";
```

Comment: This adds a border to the canvas - not to the text drawn within the canvas; I'm assuming op wants to create a border in the shape of the letters themselves.